# Redash query join with another query have big data

Tags: sql, redash, multiple-records

I am working with Redash, and I need join data from another database, Redash have [good feature](https://redash.io/help/user-guide/querying/query-results-data-source) to do this:

```
-- query_1
SELECT id, name, company_id 
FROM users

-- query_2
SELECT id, name, created_by_id, company_id 
FROM product
```

And another query use result from above query, such as:

```
-- main query
SELECT * FROM query_2 p
JOIN query_1 u on u.id = p.create_by_id
WHERE ...
AND company_id = {{ company_id }}
```

And I call `main query` use Redash API from my code:

```http
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "company_id": 1 }' http://my-redash.com/api/queries/main_query_id/results
```

My problem is main query have about 1000 records, but table `users` have a large data (~1M records), the Redash will load full data of table `user` (thought I only want users in `{{company_id}}`). And it will crash if do this.

I have consulted [this article](https://discuss.redash.io/t/thoughts-on-adding-support-for-queries-with-parameters-in-query-results-data-source/1709/2?page=2_), pass params through subqueries, but new feature is not apply.

So, my question is how to improve main query? The best solution I think is reduce the number records of query_1 but I don't know how to do this.

I need solution to reduce the number records for sub query or some other way

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this @DragonPow?

Comment: @GFoley83 now, my company use another technology to get data, it is Trino